# Why CellForRow: Calls 17 Times in Xcode 9.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I wrote a demo on Xcode 9.3. The simulator is 11.3. I created a UITableView and implemented a proxy method that uses a reuse mechanism. When I set the cell row height to display only 1 cell and Print the cellForRow: method. The print result was called 17 times. Then I used the old version of Xcode to run the same code but it was only called 2 times. This means that Xcode 9.3 does not really implement the cell reuse mechanism. Can anyone can explain this problem?

```
@interface ViewController () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    if (!_tableView) {
        _tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
        _tableView.delegate = self;
        _tableView.dataSource = self;
        [self.view addSubview:_tableView];
    }
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    //NSLog(@"%ld",indexPath.row);
    static NSString *idf = @"idf";
    //UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:idf];
    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:idf];
        NSLog(@"create");
    }
    return cell;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return 100;
}
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    return 2000;
}
@end
```

output：

```
2018-05-10 18:28:51.685711+0800 TableviewDemo[65561:3827232] create
2018-05-10 18:28:51.697077+0800 TableviewDemo[65561:3827232] create
2018-05-10 18:28:51.697953+0800 TableviewDemo[65561:3827232] create
2018-05-10 18:28:51.698667+0800 TableviewDemo[65561:3827232] create
2018-05-10 18:28:51.699238+0800 TableviewDemo[65561:3827232] create
2018-05-10 18:28:51.699804+0800 TableviewDemo[65561:3827232] create
2018-05-10 18:28:51.700625+0800 TableviewDemo[65561:3827232] create
2018-05-10 18:28:51.701282+0800 TableviewDemo[65561:3827232] create
2018-05-10 18:28:51.701997+0800 TableviewDemo[65561:3827232] create
2018-05-10 18:28:51.702789+0800 TableviewDemo[65561:3827232] create
2018-05-10 18:28:51.703488+0800 TableviewDemo[65561:3827232] create
2018-05-10 18:28:51.704152+0800 TableviewDemo[65561:3827232] create
2018-05-10 18:28:51.704767+0800 TableviewDemo[65561:3827232] create
2018-05-10 18:28:51.705374+0800 TableviewDemo[65561:3827232] create
2018-05-10 18:28:51.706024+0800 TableviewDemo[65561:3827232] create
2018-05-10 18:28:51.706673+0800 TableviewDemo[65561:3827232] create
2018-05-10 18:28:51.707334+0800 TableviewDemo[65561:3827232] create
```

Comment: Show us more code to understand the problem

Comment: Put your print statement into the `if (!cell) { ... }` block to check if reusing works or not.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen I put log in if(!cell){} as you said,but still printed 17 times.If the screen can only show one cell, i think it should only be called twice to achieve performance optimization. Instead of 17 times

Comment: @rv7284 Code has been edited

Comment: You are giving the number of rows 100. So depending on the device size. Whatever the number of the rows will be rendered. that many time cell for row method will be called.

Comment: @rv7284 If the screen only could display one cell，why create 10+ cells into a buffer pool?

Comment: That is a very very very old way of creating cells. You should be dequeueing with the indexpath.

Comment: @rv7284 I changed my code,maybe u can understand what’s the problem is

Comment: @Fogmeister I have try,but the same problem.

Comment: @He.Kevin it won't fix the problem. :D It just should be updated :D

Comment: @Fogmeister okey,thank u very much, i will be use the new method after, and, u know this problem also?

Answer (score 0):

I check this from a little demo. in if code

```
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:idf];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor cyanColor];
}
```

will be call the number of rows in tableview. But there is only contain UITableViewCellContentView and _UITableViewCellSeparatorView. I hope this will help you.